# Cypress : How to use keyboard Events

Tags: typescript, cucumber, cypress, bdd, chai

In Runtime, I have to press <kbd>Esc</kbd> or <kbd>Enter</kbd> button (Keyboard event). For this, I have tried with below syntax,

```
cy.type("{enter}")
cy.type("{enter}")
cy.focused().tab().click()
```

But it's not worked for me. Could suggest me how to achieve this in cypress.

Comment: Please add the HTML of your element.

Answer (score 2):

in the code above you should remove `.tab()`

```
  cy.type("{enter}")
  cy.type("{enter}")
  cy.focused().click()
```

or probably you forgot to add selector

```
  cy.get('selector')
    .type("{enter}")
    .type("{enter}")
    .focused().click()
```

because `.type()` yields the same subject it was given from the previous command. [docs](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/type#Arguments)